# No Safetensor Weights found - Hugging Face Docker Chat UI

Tags: docker, large-language-model, huggingface

I wanted to build a HuggingFace space, using BioMistral 7B and the Docker Chat UI Template. Unfortunately it gives me following error:

> `2024-03-11T17:18:50.175605Z  WARN text_generation_launcher: No safetensors weights found for model biomistral/BioMistral-7B at revision None. Downloading PyTorch weights. 2024-03-11T17:18:50.204434Z  INFO text_generation_launcher: Download file: pytorch_model.bin 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 10 seconds. 59 retries  Warning: left.`

It keeps running and fails, also when naming another model in .gguf with safetensor files. Anybody knows why?